# Is there a word for the feeling of having messed up?

Tags: single-word-requests, emotions

How would you describe that burning emotion of having messed up? It's a mix of guilt and being deeply unsettled, together with crushing embarrassment.

Examples;

-When he realized he had given his wife AIDS, he was overcome by deep [word].

-She checked her account balance and realized with [word] that she had underestimated how expensive the mortgage really was.

-After becoming a cuckold, he realized With [word] that he couldn't call himself a real man anymore.

Comment: Simple is sometimes best, think "shame".

Comment: You're right, of course. It just doesn't feel as harsh and humiliating as what I want to convey. I wish there were words to convey discreet levels or shades of shame, if that makes sense.

Comment: You might try adding an adjective to "shame".  You can then shade as you wish.

Comment: "Mortification" might fill the bill.

Answer (score 3):

There are some, I need them too often.

**remorse**

From [merriam-webster definition of remorse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remorse):
1 : a gnawing distress arising from a sense of guilt for past wrongs

**self-reproach**  ([self_reproach](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-reproach))

harsh criticism or disapproval of oneself especially for wrongdoing

For your examples, also **regret** would be an option. [regret in merriam-wbester](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regret)

Answer (score -3):

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:

DISORDER 
: an abnormal physical or mental condition:
a liver disorder
a personality 
disorder.